# How install and run latest Apache and PHP Server over EC2 user data PowerShell script for window instance

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell, ec2-userdata

I am beginner to this PowerShell script.
Please help me with this as I got stuck here.
I'm using this user data given below in ec2 window instance launch config So,
how can we proceed here can we get the same way as we are getting in code deployment agent for both php and apache latest version.
I am not aware of the PowerShell script for invoking apache and php version.

UserData: !Base64
'Fn::Join':
- |+

```
      - - <powershell>
        - Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
        - Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
        - Add-WindowsFeature Web-Http-Redirect
        - Add-WindowsFeature Web-Windows-Auth
        - Import-Module AWSPowerShell           
        - New-Item -Path "c:\codedeploy" -ItemType "directory" -Force
        - Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/codedeploy-agent.msi -OutFile c:\codedeploy\codedeploy-agent.msi
        - c:\codedeploy\codedeploy-agent.msi /quiet /l c:\codedeploy\host-agent-install-log.txt 
        - New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "Apache24" -Type "directory"

        - </powershell>
```

Comment: How is this problem related to PHP, or programming?

Comment: It's related to writing the script to download and install the php and apache web servers.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If PHP is involved, please share the code